# reading tif file using terra and raster package gives different results

Tags: r, raster, terra

I am reading a raster file using both terra and raster package

```
library(raster)
library(terra)

fl_terra <- terra::rast('my_raster.tif')
fl_raster <- raster::raster('my_raster.tif')
  
fl_terra
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 157450, 327979, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.0002777778, 0.0002777778  (x, y)
extent      : -142.4107, -51.30541, 41.12569, 84.86181  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
source      : xxxx.tif 
categories  : DepthBand 
name        :         DepthBand 
min value   : 0.0m <= x <= 0.3m 
max value   :          x > 9.0m 

fl_raster
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 157450, 327979, 51640293550  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.0002777778, 0.0002777778  (x, y)
extent     : -142.4107, -51.30541, 41.12569, 84.86181  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : xxxx.tif 
names      : DepthBand 
values     : 1, 6  (min, max)
```

Why is reading the same file using the two packages showing different values?
If I open the same file in QGIS, the legend displays the values present in the `fl_raster` i.e. using the `raster` package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file has categorical values. `fl_terra` tells you that:

```
categories  : DepthBand
```

And it also properly shows the (alphabetical) range of the categories (and it also uses them in the legend when using plot, and returns them when extracting cell values).

```
name        :         DepthBand 
min value   : 0.0m <= x <= 0.3m 
max value   :          x > 9.0m
```

If you do not care about the categories, you can remove them with

```
levels(fl_terra) <- NULL
```

In contrast, `fl_raster` shows the numerical codes that are used to represent the categories (because the raster files can only store numeric cell values).

```
values     : 1, 6  (min, max)
```

That makes it look like you have numeric values. But that is not the case.

The situation is similar to having a factor in R

```
f <- as.factor(c("red", "blue", "green"))
```

"terra" would show the category labels

```
f
#[1] red   blue  green
#Levels: blue green red
```

Whereas "raster" would show the equivalent of

```
as.integer(f)
#[1] 3 1 2
```

Comment: Okay thanks. I looked at the documentation and I can do `catalyze(fl_terra)` to get the numbers

Comment: You can remove the levels with `levels(fl_terra) <- NULL`